# PHP regular expression to match alpha-numeric strings with some (but not all) punctuation

Tags: php, regex, performance, alphanumeric, punctuation

I've written a regular expression in PHP to allow strings that are alpha-numeric with any punctuation except **&** or **@**. Essentially, I need to allow anything on a standard American keyboard with the exception of those two characters. It took me a while to come up with the following regex, which seems to be doing what I need:

```
if (ereg("[^]A-Za-z0-9\[!\"#$%'()*+,./:;<=>?^_`{|}~\-]", $test_string)) {
  // error message goes here
}
```

Which brings me to my question... is there a better, simpler, or more efficient way?

Comment: `ereg` is deprecated.  Consider using `preg_match` instead.  And don't forget to anchor your regular expression.

Comment: ereg are deprecated used `preg_match`

Comment: You really [shouldn’t use A-Z to mean alphanumerics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955086/sort-upper-case-just-before-lowercase-key-values-from-a-hash/4958634#4958634) anymore. That’s why we have things like `\w`, or `[\pL\pN]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at character ranges:

`@[!-%'-?A-~]+@`

This will exclude the characters `& (\0x26)` and `@ (0x40)`.
Looking at an [ASCII Table](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~pham/ascii_table.jpg),you can see how this works:
The exclamation mark is the first character in the ASCII set, that is not whitespace. It will then match everything up to and including the `%` character, which immediately precedes the ampersand. Then the next range until the `@` character, which lies between `?` and `A`. After that, we match everything unto the end of the standard ASCII character set which is a `~`.

## Update

To make things more readable, you might also consider to do this in two steps:
At first, filter anything outside of the default ASCII range.

`@[!-~]+@`

In a second step, filter your undesired characters, or simply do a `str_pos` on the characters.

At the end, you can compare it with what you started to see whether it contained any undesired characters.

Instead, you could also use a regex such as this for the second step.
`/[^@&]+/`

The steps are interchangeable and doing a str_pos on `@` or `&` as a first step, to identify bad characters, may be better performance wise.

Comment: phant0m, !preg_match("@[!-%'-?A-~]+@", $test_string) appears to match just what I needed. Thanks! Can you explain what the @ at the beginning and the +@ at the end are doing though? So far, my search for an explanation has been unsuccessful. Thanks again!

Comment: It is the delimiter for the search pattern. You can replace them with any other character, but it shouldn't be used within the pattern, else you have to escape it. After the delimiters, you can set options such as case independent and other stuff, but that is of no use here.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. I didn't realize that "the preg functions allow any non-alphanumeric character as regex delimiters." (from: http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html). Thanks!

Comment: I had to make an additional modification because it wasn't weeding out things like "1@2345&". Here's what I have now... if (!preg_match('@^[!-%\'-?A-~]*$@i', $form_state['values']['pass'])) {

Comment: Ah yes.. it would be smart to force it for the entire test string :)

Comment: Just FYI, the link to the ASCII table image is broken.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
[^&@]
```

with `preg_match`

```
$str = 'a';
var_dump(preg_match('~^[^&@]+$~', $str)); // true

$str = '&';
var_dump(preg_match('~^[^&@]+$~', $str)); // false

$str = '!';
var_dump(preg_match('~^[^&@]+$~', $str)); // true
```

Comment: I can type characters like `ä ö ü`. If you do not whitelist the characters, you cannot be sure of the result you will get. Not that I could see the purpose really - but it wouldn't guarantee that the input matches the desired pattern, as you cannot possibly blacklist all disallowed characters.

Comment: Yes, I needed to weed out foreign characters to.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than testing for all the alpha numeric characters you can simply check for @ and & and use a not?

```
$reg = '/@|&/';
if(!preg_match($reg, "YOUR STRING CAN GO HERE")){
// your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Same snag here: You blacklist characters while I can enter anything that you forgot to blacklist, which is quite a lot.