# PHP regular expression: string must contain to types of characters

Tags: php, regex

Following up on [PHP regular expression to match alpha-numeric strings with some (but not all) punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468442/php-regular-expression-to-match-alpha-numeric-strings-with-some-but-not-all-pun), I need to accept at least 2 types of characters that must be one of number, letter, or punctuation, for a string that must be between 6 and 18 chars in length.  Is this the best way to do so?  I constructed this regex using the pattern from [RegExLib](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=31).

```
preg_match('@' .  
// one number and one letter  
'^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[!-%\'-?A-~]{6,18}$' .  
// one number and one punctuation  
'|^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!-%\'-/:-?\[-`{-~])[!-%\'-?A-~]{6,18}$' .  
// or one punctation and one  
'|^(?=.*[!-%\'-/:-?\[-`{-~])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[!-%\'-?A-~]{6,18}$' .  
'@i', $pass, $matches);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is too complicated. Just check the existence of the char types and the length.

```
<?php
$is_special = preg_match('/[+#!\?]/', $pass); //sample only
$is_numeric = preg_match('/[0-9]/', $pass);
$is_char = preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $pass);

if ($is_special + $is_numeric + $is_char < 2) {
    //fail
}

//+lenght check
```

Answer (score 1):

That regex won't work since if you feed all three types, you'll get rejected.

To build one would be quite verbose since you need to account for all possibilities of combinations:

1. Letter - Digit
2. Digit - Letter
3. Letter - Punctuation
4. Punctuation - Letter
5. Digit - Punctuation
6. Punctuation - Digit
7. Letter - Digit - Punctuation
8. Letter - Punctuation - Digit
9. Digit - Letter - Punctuation
10. Digit - Punctuation - Letter
11. Punctuation - Letter - Digit
12. Punctuation - Digit - Letter

Instead, I'd suggest doing it manually:

```
function isValidString($string) {
    $count = 0;
    //Check for the existence of each type of character:
    if (preg_match('/\d/', $string)) {
        $count++;
    }
    if (preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $string)) {
        $count++;
    }
    if (preg_match('/[!-%\'-\/:-?\[-{-~]/', $string)) 
        $count++;
    }
    //Check the whole string
    $regex = '/^[a-z\d!-%\'-\/:-?\[-{-~]{6,18}$/';
    if ($count >= 2 && preg_match($regex, $string)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's about as long as your regex would be, and it's more readable (IMHO)...

Comment: I tested my regex with all three types and it still worked.  The lookahead takes care of the ordering as well.  But i see how yours is more readable and works.

Answer (score 1):

erenon's solution erroneously allows spaces. (It needs to add a check for valid chars when it checks for length).
Here's how I would do it:

```php
if (preg_match('&
    # Password with 6-18 chars from 2 of 3 types: (digits|letters|punct).
    ^                            # Anchor to string start.
    (?:                          # Non-capture group for alternatives.
      (?=.*?[0-9])               # Either a digit
      (?=.*?[a-zA-Z])            #   and a letter,
    | (?=.*?[0-9])               # Or a digit
      (?=.*?[!-%\'-/:-?[-`{-~])  #   and a punctuation,
    | (?=.*?[!-%\'-/:-?[-`{-~])  # Or a punctuation
      (?=.*?[a-zA-Z])            #   and a letter.
    )                            # End group of alternatives.
    [!-%\'-?A-~]{6,18}$          # Match between 6 and 18 valid chars.
    &x', $password)) {
    // Good password
} else {
    // Bad password
}
```

Note that the length criteria only needs to be checked once. Also, it is likely faster than any of the other solution so far.

Comment: Why a space isn't valid in a password?

Comment: A space is not included in the original post's regex character class used to check the length. But you're right that this is not explicitly spelled out in the wording of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is it in one regex :

`/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])([A-Za-z0-9_!@#$%^&*-\[\]])+$/`

allow small-capital-numeric and special chars
check if password contains at least one char and one number