# Need help to create one regex for password validation

Tags: javascript, ios, regex, validation

I need one regex which validates below condition for password entered by user:

1. it must have at least one capital letter
2. it must have at least one number
3. It must have at least one special character

I need regex to implement it in javascript.

I have tried this one

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+|~-=\`{}[]:";'<>?,])/i;
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: just edited my question with what i have tried

Comment: Why do you have `(?=.*[a-z])`? Also you need to escape `[]` in a character class.

Comment: Duplicate. This question gets asked a lot. I'm partial to my own answer(s). See: "[regex for password](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611715/433790)" and "[Regular expression for a string that must contain minimum 14 characters, where at minimum 2 are numbers, and at minimum 6 are letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5527428/433790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the rules you mentioned:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])/;
```

This should suffice.

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` matches anything that is not an alphabet and not a number, i.e. a special character.

I removed the case insensitive flag because you specifically mentioned there should be 1 uppercase letter.