# Input validation with Python 3.4: can only contain

Tags: regex, validation, python-3.x

I would like to allow these characters `[a-z]+\.+[0-9]*\_*` (Must contain one or more lowercase alphabetical characters(a-z) and Must contain one or more periods(.) also can contain zero or more digits(0-9), zero or more underscores(_)) , but no others.

I have tried multiple ways without success:

```
import re
iStrings = str(input('Enter string? '))
iMatch = re.findall(r'[a-z]+\.+[0-9]*\_*', iStrings)
iiMatch = re.findall(r'[~`!@$%^&*()-+={}\[]|\;:\'"<,>.?/]', iStrings)
iiiMatch = iMatch != iiMatch
if iiiMatch:
    print(':)')
else:
    print(':(')
```

Another example:

```
import re
iStrings = str(input('Enter string? '))
iMatch = re.findall(r'[a-z]+\.+[0-9]*\_*', iStrings) not "[~`!@$%^&*()-+={}\[]|\;:\'"<,>.?/]" in iStrings 
if iMatch:
   print(':)')
else:
   print(':(')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: added clarification.

Edit: For additional information: https://forums.uberent.com/threads/beta-mod-changes.51520/page-8#post-939265

Comment: FYI added Python code to the answer.

Comment: For a more generalized take on input validation, (to which this question is a simplified example of), take a look at some (of the _many_) password validatiuon questions and answers: e.g. [regex for password](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611715/433790)

Comment: @ridgerunner nice link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allow these characters [a-z]+\.+[0-9]*\_*
```

First off, `[a-z]+` is not "a" character. Neither is `[0-9]*` nor `\_*`

I am assuming that you mean you want to allow letters, digits, underscores, dots, plusses and asterisks.

Try this:

```
^[\w*.+]+$
```

1. The `\w` already matches `[a-z]`, `[0-9]` and `_`
2. The anchors `^` and `$` ensure that nothing else is allowed.
3. From your question I wasn't clear if you wanted to allow a `+` character to match. If not, remove it from the character class: `^[\w*.]+$`. Likewise, remove the `*` if it isn't needed.

In code:

```
if re.search(r"^[\w*.+]+$", subject):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

EDIT following your comment:

For a string that must contain one or more letter, AND one or more dot, AND zero or more _, AND zero or more digits, we need lookaheads to enforce the `one or more` conditions. You can use this:

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\.)[\w_.]+$`

Comment: Sorry about that wasn't clear. Lower case characters `[a-z]` one or more, one or more `.`, zero or more `_` and zero more `[0-9]`. it's my first time using regex and man is it confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @loki_999 Thanks for your feedback. Are you saying that the expression must contain one or more letter, AND one or more dot, AND zero or more _, AND zero or more digits? Then that's a different regex `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\.)[\w_.]+$` (we need to use lookaheads for validation)

Comment: Exactly. https://forums.uberent.com/threads/beta-mod-changes.51520/page-8#post-939265

Comment: @loki_999 Well that's alright then since I added that to the answer as well. :)