# Regular expression to match minimum password requirements and other characters

Tags: php, regex

I want users signing up on my site to choose passwords that include:

- Minimum of 8 characters
- At least one uppercase
- At least one lowercase
- At least one digit.
  But these are the minimum requirements. They can include any characters such as @,#,&, etc. as long as these requirements are met. I have the following regex:

  `/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)\w{8,20}$/`

But it doesn't match other characters asides those in the requirements listed above. I want to be able match a password that can contain any character but still meet the conditions above. How do i do this?

Comment: Change the `\w`s of which your password must consist to something more (`\S`, `.`)

Comment: Please do a search next time. This question gets asked and answered a _LOT_. e.g. [regex for password](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611715/433790)

Comment: @ridgerunner Noted. But i did do a research and wrote my own regex. Just needed a little help matching minimum requirements + other characters and now i understand it.

Comment: It's an old question, but as someone who frequently encounters bizarre and unhelpful password requirements, I must query forcing your users to enter a digit and mix case. [Lengthy passwords are always more secure](https://xkcd.com/936/) than short passwords containing random digits and characters. The former are easy to remember and hard for computers to crack; the latter are impossible to remember and easy for computers to crack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/
```

[Demo on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xE8jL9)

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XjQSVc6dOdP1rmfp)

Explanation:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` requires an uppercase character
- `(?=.*[a-z])` requires a lowercase character
- `(?=.*\d)` requires a digit
- `.{8,}` requires minimum length of 8.

**Note:** Unlike anubhava's answer, this allows for whitespace characters. If you don't want whitespace, use `\S` as suggested by anubhava.

**Edit:** Per the excellent point by @ridgerunner in the comments, here is a slightly more efficient regex:

```
/^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d).{8,}$/
```

This version avoids the lazy `.*` expression, which wastes time in testing the overall regex in this context.

Comment: Note that you can make this regex more efficient by changing the lazy dot stars to more precise greedy expressions: `/^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d).{8,}$/`

Comment: @ridgerunner Please can you explain to me how this regex you suggested is more efficient?

Comment: @ss_millionaire - Well, I could, but not within the limited confines of a comment here. The short answer is that the greedy expression requires fewer steps for the regex engine to declare a match. (Lazy quantifiers require one backtrack per character - a greedy one can consume them all in a single step.) I can, however, strongly recommend the following book: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!") where regex efficiency is covered in great detail.

Comment: @ss_millionaire As ridgerunner says, it's complicated. The short version is that `.` matches everything other than `\r` and `\n` by default. So, in matching `(?=.*[A-Z])` against `foo Bar`, the regex engine would gobble up the entire string in trying to match `.*`, then back up until it got to a character in `[A-Z]` (`B` in this case). With `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])`, on the other hand, `B` doesn't match `[^A-Z]`. So, the engine just goes forward through `foo `, then matches `B`. This saves the extra steps of walking forward and backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it all in one regex.  It is far more readable and maintainable to make each validation its own check.

```
$passes =
    preg_match( '/[A-Z]/', $pw ) && # uppercase char
    preg_match( '/[a-z]/', $pw ) && # lowercase char
    preg_match( '/\d/', $pw ) &&    # digit
    (strlen($pw) > 8);              # at least 8 characters
```

Comment: I don't think PHP has a `length()` function. Did you mean `strlen()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)\S{8,20}$/
```

I have used `\S` (any non space character) instead of `\w` (word character that means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

Comment: This does not allow for whitespace (which is acceptable in http://xkcd.com/936/), which you may want to allow.

Comment: Yes it doesn't allow spaces because OP didn't ask for it.