# Regex - how to ignore order of the matched groups?

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I'm trying to create a regex validation for a password which is meant to be:

1. 6+ characters long
2. Has at least one a-z
3. Has at least one A-Z
4. Has at leat one 0-9

So, in other words, the match will have :

1. at least one a-z, A-Z, 0-9
2. at least 3 any other characters

I've came up with:

```
((.*){3,}[a-z]{1,}[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,})
```

it seems pretty simple and logical to me, but 2 things go wrong:

1. quantifier `{3,}` for `(.*)` somehow doesn't work and destroys whole regex. At first I had `{6,}` at the end but then regex would affect the quantifiers in inner groups, so it will require `[A-Z]{6,}` instead of `[A-Z]{1,}`
2. when I remove `{3,}` the regex works, but will match only if the groups are in order - so that it will match `aaBB11`, but not `BBaa11`

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466850/complex-password-regular-expression). You might change your mind about using regex to do what you want.

Comment: I have found a very similar answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14850765/1650907

Comment: Please do a search first - this question gets asked (and answered) a LOT - e.g. [regex for password](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611715/433790). I also recommend the following blog post: [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password REGEX with min 6 chars, at least one letter and one number and may contain special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7844359/1255289)

Answer (score 8):

This is a use case where I wouldn't use a single regular expression, but multiple simpler ones.

**Still, to answer your question:** If you only want to validate that the password matches those criteria, you could use lookaheads:

```
^(?=.{6})(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])
```

You're basically looking for a position from which you look at

- 6 characters (and maybe more to follow, doesn't matter): `(?=.{6})`
- maybe something, then a lowercase letter: `(?=.*?[a-z])`
- maybe something, then an uppercase letter: `(?=.*?[A-Z])`
- maybe something, then a digit: `(?=.*?[0-9])`

The order of appearance is arbitrary due to the *maybe something* parts.

(Note that I've interpreted *6 characters long* as *at least 6 characters long*.)

Comment: Good idea, since this is just what I need - a validating pattern, not a match for the password itself. However, I still don't know how to ignore order of matched groups...

Comment: Yeah, and if the question means *exactly 6 characters long* just change `(?=.{6})` to `^(?=.{6}$)`

Comment: An issue here is that `.` matches any character except newline (so the password might include spaces, tabs...)

Comment: @antithesis: ...but not newlines.

Comment: Unfortunetely it doesn't work for input's `pattern` attribute

Comment: Your pattern is correct, however if you don't anchor it at the begining of the string with `^`, with an invalid password, each lookahead will be tested at each position in the string (i.e. from the start, after the first character, after the second, etc.). With the `^` the pattern will fail when the first lookahead fails, and lookeads are tested zero or one time only.

Comment: Example with `abcdefghij`: (anchored: 22 steps before failing, without anchor: 103 steps), with `abcdefghijabcdefghij` (a:32s, wa: 358s), and the number of steps for the pattern without anchor to fail is growing exponentially with the string length.

Comment: Among other problems, right now this would allow this for a password: `my robot is called R2d2`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Of course, silly me. Thanks for pointing out `^`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[!-~]{6,}$
```

If we follow your spec to the letter, your validation password looks like this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$
```

However, we need to improve on this, because apart from the number, lower-case and upper-case letter, are you really willing to accept any character? For instance, can the user use a character in the Thai language? A space character? A tab? Didn't think so. :)

If you want to allow all the printable [ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) apart from space, instead of a dot, we can use this character range: `[!-~]`

**How does it work?**

- The `^` anchor makes sure we start the match at the start of the string
- The `(?=.*[a-z])` lookahead ensures we have a lower-case character
- The `(?=.*[A-Z])` lookahead ensures we have an upper-case character
- The `(?=.*[0-9])` lookahead ensures we a digit
- The `(?=.*[a-z])` lookahead ensures we have a lower-case character
- The `[!-~]{6,}` matches six or more ASCII printable ASCII characters that are not space.
- The `$` ensures we have reached the end of the string (otherwise, the password could contain more characters that are not allowed).

Answer (score 1):

you could use this pattern `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}`