# Regex for password ver

Tags: php, html, regex

I an currently working on a login form and I am trying to make a password field accept some conditions with a regex. The conditions are:

```
-Accept at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter
-accept at least one number
-accept at least one special character except $ % & | < > #
```

I am still new at coding, and for now i am using a plugin called parsley for the validations, but this is what i made by watching some tutos and using https://regex101.com/

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\$\%\&\|\<\>\#])
```

but at one point it starts to accept the forbidden special characters. Is there any other way to improve my regex?

Comment: Might be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24232582/5348487

Comment: One upper `^(?=.*[A-Z])`, one lower `^(?=.*[a-z])`, one number `^(?=.*\d)`,  one special char `^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d$%&|<>#\s])` Fwiw - it's easier to know what special characters are first.

Comment: In the current incarnation `[^\$\%\&\|\<\>\#]` will match a-z, A-Z, or \d. So, since one of those are required, this will always pass. Special characters should be matched _positively_. Otherwise, example [^x] matches a lot of stuff.

Comment: I tested your regex, but it still accept $ % & | < > # at some point.

Comment: try this    ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$%&|<>#]).*$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password REGEX with min 6 chars, at least one letter and one number and may contain special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7844359/1255289)