# Regex to extract all words from text that have a least one number

Tags: php, regex

How would I match all words that have at least one digit/number in multiline text block? I found this, [Regular expression for a string that must contain minimum 14 characters, where at minimum 2 are numbers, and at minimum 6 are letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527191/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-must-contain-minimum-14-characters-where-a), which works for a single string. I get the concept of lookaheads, but not in my scenario since I make a `preg_match_all()`. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex for searching all words with at least a digit in it:

```
\b\w*?\d\w*\b
```

To make it unicode safe use:

```
/\b\w*?\p{N}\w*\b/u
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQ0eL8/2)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/\b\w*?\p{N}\w*\b/u'; 
preg_match_all($re, $input, $matches);
```

Comment: yes this works good enough for me! thx thought it would be more complicated but forgot about word boundary